# Strange behaviour of (D)NAT

Tags: linux, iptables, tcpdump, iptables-redirect

I'm trying to forward all icmp requests from `source ip 5.10.13.13` to new `destination ip 5.10.11.11`. IP of current local machine, where i'm applying iptables rule is `5.10.10.10`. I apply this rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p icmp –icmp-type 8 -s 5.10.13.13 -j DNAT –to-destination 5.10.11.11
```

The issue is in replying to this icmp request from `5.10.10.10`. 
In other words, in my tcpdump

```
tcpdump -ni eth0 -p
```

I saw this records:

```
IP 5.10.10.10 > 5.10.11.11 ICMP echo request
IP 5.10.10.10 > 5.10.13.13 ICMP echo reply
```

Question: Why forwarding of icmp request works normally, but replying to this icmp request working too